# Identifying a near future Sci-fi novel where Rainforests are now a global treasure, with wars launched to take them over

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for this book that I am trying to identify from memory:

- It is a sci-fi novel taking place in the near-future
- It was definitely printed before 2005, as I remembered borrowing it from my polytechnic library and I left there before 2005
- Rainforests are now a global treasure, wars and peacekeeping operations are launched to take over these rainforests; the Malaysian jungles are one of them
- The Genting Casino, at the top of [Genting Highlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genting_Highlands) in Malaysia, was mentioned as a site, but I can't remember the context in which it happened. I think some warlord/military leader took over it?

That is about all I can accurately remember.

Comment: Do you remember if there were other planets involved? Or was it set solely on Earth?

Comment: it was solely set on earth, I remembered global warming was a huge issue and rainforests are almost extinct, which is why the UN sends peackeeeping forests against other countries to take over the last few remaining forests.

Comment: "Peacekeeping forests" makes me think of ents wearing blue helmets.